# How do I change the value of an individual cell in a WPF datagrid when it is double clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid that lists the status of a couple things and displays either "True" or "False". When I double click on a cell, I want to toggle what that cell displays. I've tried using a number of properties for my datagrid, such as currentItem, SelectedItem, SelectedValue, and SelectedUnit, but none of these have worked.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" IsReadOnly="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False" Width="250" Height="468"  Margin="795,15,18,15" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" MouseDoubleClick="DoubleClick" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Availability}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Key, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status1" Binding="{Binding Value1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status2" Binding="{Binding Value2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here's the event in my codebehind:

```
private void DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid1.SelectedItem == null) return;

    if (dataGrid1.CurrentItem == "True" )
    {
        dataGrid1.CurrentItem = "False";
    }
    else if (dataGrid1.CurrentItem == "False")
    {
        dataGrid1.CurrentItem = "True";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your DataGrid is bound to a data source, so you will need to update that data source, and then reload the data.

Comment: I know how to determine which row is clicked by using the dataGrid1.SelectedIndex, but how do I determine which column is clicked? For example, if I double click on an arbitrary row in the middle column, that is associated with Value1. How do I tell my dataSource that it needs to toggle Value1 and not Value2?

Comment: It would seem as if I needed something like dataGrid1.SelectedColumn, but I don't see that property listed on msdn's website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna know which DataGridCell is being double-clicked, you must add this to your XAML:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="dataGrid1_CellDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

And then in your code-behind, handle the event:

```
private void dataGrid1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as DataGridCell;

    // Do stuff with your cell
}
```

The problem is... Your DataGrid and columns are databound, so *most* things you do to your cell's content won't reflect in your actual data.

I say "*most*", because you could, in fact, change the cell text and the value of the databound property at the same time... But it's quite dirty and doesn't really belong in the view.

```
private void dataGrid1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as DataGridCell;

    if (cell != null && cell.Content is TextBlock)
    {
        var textBlock = cell.Content as TextBlock;
        textBlock.SetCurrentValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "put your text here");
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(textBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty);
        binding.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

For this to work, you have to set `Mode=TwoWay` on your DataGridTextColumn Bindings (though it may already be the default mode, I don't remember). Also, it won`t work with other types of columns.

BUT... As I said, this solution is dirty and you want to have that kind of logic in your viewmodel.

The easiest way to do that could be exposing a method from your viewmodel, that you could call from code-behind passing some parameters like the row's data item and the column's property name.

```
private void dataGrid1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as DataGridCell;

    if (cell != null)
    {
        (this.DataContext as MyViewModel).DoStuff(cell.DataContext, cell.Column.SortMemberPath);
    }
}
```